# How can I print only the keys of inner dictionaries that are nested within a list, within a dict, in alphabetical order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Ideally, the result of the print would be:

```
- ainner  
- binner1  
- cinner2  
- dinner3
```

However I've only managed to print out the keys using `.keys()`.

```
json_dict = {"key": "value", "key1": [{"binner": "inner_value"}, {"ainner1": "inner_value1"}, {"cinner": "inner_value"}, {"dinner1": "inner_value1"}]}

def pprint(a_dict):
    for k in a_dict["key1"]:
        print("-", k.keys())

pprint(json_dict)
```

This results in:

```
- dict_keys(['binner'])
- dict_keys(['ainner1'])    
- dict_keys(['dinner1'])
- dict_keys(['cinner'])
```

I am looking for similar functionality as this:
`{print("- {}".format(k)) for k in sorted(a_dict)}` which works for a non-nested dictionary

Comment: You have four expected outputs listed; however, this dictionary could only provide two, namely "binner" and "ainner1". Could you clarify?

Comment: @Ajax1234 Sure--I figured it was self-explanatory enough. I'll add another 2 inner-dicts to make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
json_dict = {"key": "value", "key1": [{"binner": "inner_value"}, {"ainner1": "inner_value1"}, {"cinner": "inner_value"}, {"dinner1": "inner_value1"}]}
new_data = sorted([list(i.keys())[0] for i in json_dict["key1"]])
```

Output:

```
['ainner1', 'binner', 'cinner', 'dinner1']
```

Comment: Presumably this is supposed to be _generalized_, not hardcoded  to work only for the OP's specific example.

Comment: `keys()` is not able to be indexed

Answer (score 2):

What you want to return is the name of the keys.

```
json_dict = {"key": "value", "key1": [{"binner": "inner_value"},{"ainner1": "inner_value1"}]}

for i in json_dict['key1']:
    for x in i.keys():
        print (x)
```

It results in this

```
binner
ainner1
```

You will need to iterate over .keys() to access keys name.

Answer (score 0):

Once you *have* the object you want (`key1`'s value)

```
a = [{"binner": "inner_value"}, {"ainner1": "inner_value1"},
     {"cinner": "inner_value"}, {"dinner1": "inner_value1"}]

import itertools
```

Get the keys from each dictionary

```
b = map(dict.keys, a)
```

Flatten the list of [key view objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys)

```
c = itertools.chain.from_iterable(b)
```

sort

```
d = sorted(c)
```

print

```
fmt_s = '- {}'
for thing in d:
    print(fmt_s.format(thing))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted does most of the job, changing `pprint` from:

```
def pprint(a_dict):
    for k in a_dict["key1"]:
       print("-", k.keys())
```

to

```
def pprint(a_dict):
    for k in a_dict["key1"]:
        print("-", list(k.keys())[0])
```

yields:

```
- binner
- ainner1
- cinner
- dinner1
```